# Query extremely slow because of sub-queries

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to to port some data to a new structure but it's taking me forever.

The query is the following:

```
INSERT INTO atemp_addresses (id, city, state, country_id)
SELECT id, (SELECT name from cities WHERE id=adr.city_id limit 1),
(SELECT name FROM states WHERE id=(SELECT state_id FROM cities WHERE id=adr.city_id limit 1) limit 1), (SELECT country_id FROM states WHERE id=(SELECT state_id FROM cities WHERE id=adr.city_id limit 1) limit 1), FROM addresses adr
```

Because the data is held in other tables, I have to use all those subqueries, which slows it down a lot. Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: "Because the data is held in other tables, I have to use all those subqueries" ... you should be joining the tables together in the FROM clause.

Comment: I know I may sound rude, but, do you mind helping me with this? I never used joins before, never understood how they work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your query:

```
INSERT INTO atemp_addresses (id, city, state, country_id)
    SELECT id,
           (SELECT name from cities WHERE id = adr.city_id limit 1),
           (SELECT name FROM states WHERE id = (SELECT state_id FROM cities WHERE id=adr.city_id limit 1) limit 1),
           (SELECT country_id FROM states WHERE id=(SELECT state_id FROM cities WHERE id=adr.city_id limit 1) limit 1)
    FROM addresses adr;
```

Repeatedly, you are using `LIMIT` without an `ORDER BY`.  This means that you are going to get an arbitrary matching row that can change from one invocation to the next.

The equivalent query should be:

```
INSERT INTO atemp_addresses (id, city, state, country_id)
    SELECT adr.id, c.name, s.name, s.country_id
    FROM addresses adr JOIN
         cities c
         ON adr.city_id = c.id JOIN
         states s
         ON c.state_id = s.id;
```

Your use of `LIMIT` suggests that there might be more than one city with the same `id` (a sign of poor database design?).  If so:

```
INSERT INTO atemp_addresses (id, city, state, country_id)
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (adr.id) adr.id, c.name, s.name, s.country_id
    FROM addresses adr JOIN
         cities c
         ON adr.city_id = c.id JOIN
         states s
         ON c.state_id = s.id 
    ORDER BY adr.id;
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, sorry for this. I used limits for performance, I saw that if I limit it to 1, it will be faster, probably because it will stop searching once it finds the entry.

Comment: If `id` column is a primary key - postgresql query optimiser should be smart enough to infer it itself.

Comment: Okay so, your query did the job, in 31 seconds(my query did not finish in hours). One problem I see now is that it did not move all the entries. Some addresses may have city_id = 0 which means they don't have a matching entry in cities table. The join would just make it skip the address entry since it doesn't find a match in the others, am I correct?

If so, is there a way I can move them all, even if city_id is not present in cities?

Also, for now, I want to thank you a lot. You helped me make a huge progress and your example just made me understand how JOIN works.

Comment: I managed to make it move all the entries, even those with ho matching entry in the other tables, by using LEFT JOIN instead of JOIN.

Comment: @AndreiVreja . . . `LEFT JOIN` is the right way to do what you want.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yeah, I just realized it before posting my last comment.  Well, everything is great, you saved me from lots of headaches(already had them, now they are gone). Thank you very much for your help. I marked your answer as correct and up-rated it. 

Thank you again!

Comment: @GordonLinoff any insight into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36786949/duration-logged-but-not-the-statement-postgresql-are-there-any-specific-quer